# Calculate the remaining time of the day in different time

Tags: java, time, timezone, timedelta, seconds

My server is running in US. Client is made a request from other than US(Australia, Singapore or IST). I want to find the remaining time of the day for the client.

How do achieve this using Java?

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of(timeZone);
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId );
int complitedSeconds = zdt.get(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_DAY);
int totalSeconds = 86400;//24*60*60
int remainingSecond = totalSeconds - complitedSeconds;
```

When i give timezone as Asia/Calcutta it is working fine. But it is not working for IST.

Anyother way to acheive this?

Comment: compute time until midnight ?

Comment: Please, “not working” is a favourite useless wording here. Instead state expected behaviour of your code and precisely in which way observed behaviour differs. So we may know more precisely what the problem is and therefore stand a greater chance of helping you.

Answer (score 4):

One issue with your code is that you assume that a day is 86400 seconds - which is not always the case, typically when changing from summer to winter time and vice versa.

A more robust approach would be to simply get a `ZonedDateTime` representing midnight and calculate the difference.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of(timeZone);
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now(zoneId);
ZonedDateTime midnight = zdt.toLocalDate().plusDays(1).atStartOfDay(zoneId);

//alternatively:
ZonedDateTime midnight = zdt.plusDays(1).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);

long seconds = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(zdt, midnight);
```

Regarding IST, please note that it could represent Irish/India/Israel Standard Time and is therefore ambiguous. It's best to use IANA time zones, like "Asia/Calcutta".

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.joda.time.Interval;
import org.joda.time.Period;

public class DateTimeUtils {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      DateTimeUtils obj = new DateTimeUtils();
      SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = 
               new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss");

      try {

        Date date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse("10/10/2013 11:30:10");
        Date date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse("13/11/2014 20:35:55");

        obj.printDifference(date1, date2);  

      } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

    }

    public void printDifference(Date startDate, Date endDate){

      Interval interval = 
               new Interval(startDate.getTime(), endDate.getTime());
      Period period = interval.toPeriod();

          System.out.printf(
           "%d years, %d months, %d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds%n", 
           period.getYears(), period.getMonths(), period.getDays(),
           period.getHours(), period.getMinutes(), period.getSeconds());

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `joda.time` and `java.util.Date` when we already have the new Date Time API in Java?